# swagger-codegen-maven-plugin with springdoc-openapi-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-codegen

I want to use springdoc-openapi-ui in a generated service with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin, but the API generated uses wrong package, it uses io.swagger.annotations instead of io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations

What can I do for that?

```java
import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import ...
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2019-10-07T13:17:04.413+02:00[Europe/Madrid]")
@Api(value = "randomPet", description = "the randomPet API")
public interface RandomPetApi {
...
}
```

```xml
<plugin>
                    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.11</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-swagger-spring-boot</id>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <inputSpec>${swagger-codegen.api.spec}</inputSpec>
                                <language>spring</language>
                                <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.web.api</apiPackage>
                                <modelPackage>${project.groupId}.web.api.model</modelPackage>
                                <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                                <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                                <additionalProperties>
                                    <java8>true</java8>
                                    <additionalProperty>jackson=true</additionalProperty>
                                </additionalProperties>
                                <library>jersey2</library>
                                <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                                <configOptions>
                                    <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
                                    <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                    <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
                                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                </configOptions>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue which lead me to read the docs: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins

By adding below line in my build.gradle fixed the issue:

```
    implementation group: 'io.swagger.parser.v3', name: 'swagger-parser', version: '2.0.20'
```

Hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 1):

You should test a newer version of swagger-codegen-maven-plugin. I had the same issue and version 3.0.27 fixed it for me.